# Just view topology errors in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology

I have a basemap (parcels), which is to be used as target for several conflation tasks. This basemap MUST NOT be modified in any way.

The basemap ist part of numerous topology rules. Each time topology is validated ArcGIS inserts vertices in the basemap and/or the other layers. I want ArcGIS to simply show errors, rather then trying to dissolve them. Assigning the highest rank to the basemap doesn't prevent ArcGIS from changing it. Finding the appropriate solution for error correction (e.g. verification of measurements in the field) or accept the error as exception is part of MY job.

How can I make ArcGIS to simply show errors without any attempt to fix them?

Answer (score 2):

Create a copy of your basemap and leave the original out of the topology rules - use the copy to be able to detect and change.

you can assign rank to each feature set

[image]

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=2612&pid=2609&topicname=Topology_in_ArcGIS

Note:
If you are dealing with Cadastral data 
COGO has much more control and accuracy
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_COGO

Comment: Thank you for that advice. I took a similar approach: convert the vertices of the original lines to points. Afterwards I delete all inserted vertices with FME.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not possible in ArcGIS topology.
Please have a look on this whiepaper from ESRI, page 11
http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/geodatabase-topology.pdf
which explain the process of validation.
Only workaround (which i am also doing) keep the minimum possible cluster tolerances then with ranks you can control the movement but you can not control the creation of nodes.